# Sidekiq can't connect to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, sidekiq, hosts-file

I have "mariadb" set to 127.0.0.1 in my /etc/hosts file and sidekiq occasionally throws errors such as:

```
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Unknown MySQL server host 'mariadb' (16)
```

The VM is not under significant load or anything like that.

Later edit: seems other gems have trouble resolving hosts too:

```
WARN -- : Unable to record event with remote Sentry server (Errno::EBUSY - Failed to open TCP connection to XXXX.ingest.sentry.io:443 (Device or resource busy - getaddrinfo)):
```

Anyone have any idea why that may happen?

Comment: Issue still happening. Seems to be related to system open files when a certain Java application is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out a couple weeks ago but wanted to be sure before posting an answer.

I still can't figure out the mechanic of this issue but it was caused by fail2ban.

I had it running in a container polling the httpd logs and blocking the tremendous amount of bots scraping my sites.

Also I increased the max file handlers and inotify handlers.

```
fs.file-max = 131070
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 65536
```

As soon as I got rid of fail2ban and increased the inotify handlers the errors disappeared.

Obviously fail2ban gets on the "do not touch" list because of this, and we've rolled out a 404/403/500 handler on application layer that pushes unknown IPs to Cloudflare.

Although this is probably an edge case I'm leaving this here in hope it helps someone at some point.